# Passing input to span field

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass the input i have from an input to an span field. I use an api dropdown list with results. So if people click on an search result it get autofilled in (much like google). I want to pass this result to an span field I have in my page.

However I dont want an onclick event if people click on an result. Rather when people click out of the input field..

This is what I tried:

```
    <div>
        <input id="exercise-search" class="form-control" type="text" name="data">
    </div>
    <span id="namespan">Name</span>
```

And the simple script:

```
        <script>

            var name = document.getElementById("exercise-search").value;
            document.getElementById("namespan").textContent=name;

            function reload(){
                var container = document.getElementById("namespan");
                var content = container.innerHTML;
                container.innerHTML= content;
            }
        </script>
```

However I still have to manually refresh the page to see the result. How can i automate this?

Comment: `reload()` just sets the element's inner HTML to the same thing.

Comment: You're setting `name` when the page is first loaded, not when the user types into the field.

Comment: Since you don't want a click event to trigger, but instead after the user leaves the input field, have you tried using the `onBlur` event to trigger updating your `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener for the `change` event to the input field. This will be executed when the user edits the field and clicks out of it.

```
document.getElementById("exercise-search").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var name = this.value;
    document.getElementById("namespan").textContent=name;
});
```